# Version control information out of sync with certain modes

Tags: magit, mode-line, git, version-control, vc-mode

Sometimes, though seemingly not in a consistent way, some modes that use version control information do not get updated correctly after `git` commands are run (e.g.,`diff-hl-mode` or `git-gutter-mode` indicate uncommitted changes though those changes have already been committed, or `vc-mode-line` will show the name of a branch that I am no longer on).

It seems to be different behaviors that trigger it, but two cases where I made note of what I did to trigger the behavior are:

1. Doing a `git rebase` from a terminal outside of emacs
2. Creating and checking out a new branch through the `magit` interface.

When this happens, it seems like `magit` is always up to speed and displays the correct information, as does `git status` from the command line of course. However, the mode-line and sometimes other packages like `diff-hl-mode` are one branch change or one commit behind.

I hope this is enough information to give someone some idea as to what could be going on. What I would like to know specifically is:

1. **What is causing this behavior?** The symptoms as described here may be too vague at the moment, but I will try to add more details as I have them. My guess is that either a mode is not updating correctly when vc information changes, or a mode that is changing vc information is not letting other modes know in the right way - but I could be way off.
2. **When this happens, how can I refresh version control information so that various modes that use the information will displays correctly?** Restarting emacs has always worked, but it would be nice to not have to resort to that.

Thank you!

Comment: Pressing `g` in the Magic status buffer seems to help. Also, https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/issues/60 could be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `diff-hl` and `magit` => `v2.4.0` you have to add this:

```cl
(add-hook 'magit-post-refresh-hook 'diff-hl-magit-post-refresh)
```

As far as the information in the mode-line is concerned, I would recommend just ignoring that (or even removing it completely). The function which updates that is actually fairly inefficient, so one could say it is a good thing it isn't called more often.

Magit once contained a function which updated the VC mode-line information whenever it updated its own buffers. That was more efficient than the original, but still rather slow.

Here's the definition.

```cl
(defun magit-refresh-vc-mode-line ()
  "Update the information displayed by `vc-mode' in the mode-line.
Like `vc-mode-line' but simpler, more efficient, and less buggy."
  (setq vc-mode
        (if vc-display-status
            (magit-with-toplevel
              (let* ((rev (or (magit-get-current-branch)
                              (magit-rev-parse "--short" "HEAD")))
                     (msg (cl-letf (((symbol-function #'vc-working-revision)
                                     (lambda (&rest _) rev)))
                            (vc-default-mode-line-string
                             'Git buffer-file-name))))
                (propertize
                 (concat " " msg)
                 'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
                 'help-echo (concat (get-text-property 0 'help-echo msg)
                                    "\nCurrent revision: " rev
                                    "\nmouse-1: Version Control menu")
                 'local-map vc-mode-line-map)))
          " Git"))
  (force-mode-line-update))
```

There no longer is a hook which is run for every file-visiting buffer belonging to a repository for which Magit is refreshing its own buffers, so you would have to write a function which you could add to `magit-post-refresh-hook`, which would then call `magit-refresh-vc-mode-line` in the appropriate buffers. `diff-hl-margin-post-refresh` might serve as inspiration.

But see [The biggest performance improvement to Emacs I've made in years](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4c0mi3/the_biggest_performance_improvement_to_emacs_ive/). Refreshing VC's mode-line information even more often might very well achieve the opposite. ;-)